# Install .NET framework Developer Pack on Fedora Linux

Tags: linux, .net-core, .net-framework-version, fedora-29

I'm developing an existing .NET core app. I use Windows and Visual Studio at work (and I was not the one setting up that environment).
But am trying to also set up an environment so I can develop from my personal laptop, where I use Fedora 29.

When building the application -  `dotnet restore && dotnet build` - I get this error:

[image: error]

I can see the dev pack can be downloaded [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/net462-developer-pack), but that's an .exe - how do I install it on Fedora Linux?

I suppose that re-targeting the application is not an option there are multiple people working on it - or maybe I could do that locally without committing the changes to shared repo?

Or is there some other workaround?

Comment: .NET Framework is available only on Windows. .NET Core is available on Windows, Linux and MacOS. There is also a Mono project, maybe it could help but I never used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Hostel noted, those are references for the older .Net frameworks that run only on Windows. You will likely need to refactor the application to use solely .Net Core libraries, possibly in a separate repo as you suggested to avoid breaking your co-workers' code.